# Python dictionary Equality Issue

Tags: python, set, equality

I am having this strange bug

I have this snippet of code:

```
for prev_cand in self.candidates: #loop over a list of dicts
  if prev_cand == cand:
    print "I think these are equal!"
    print prev_cand, cand                                                   
    print "and here are their IDs!"                                         
    print id(prev_cand), id(cand)                                           
    print "and here are their string equalities!"                           
    print str(prev_cand) == str(cand)
```

Which produced the following result:

```
I think these are equal!
{'H__0': 2} {'H__0': 1}
and here are their IDs!
27990448 27954960
and here are their string equalities!
False
```

What is going on? I am currently using a work around that just uses the string equality but that is not the right way of doing things

I added some more prints to their information:

```
and keys
['H__0'] ['H__0']
and type of keys
[<type 'str'>] [<type 'str'>]
and values
[2] [1]
and type of values
[<type 'instance'>] [<type 'instance'>]
```

I'm trying to make a small reproducible code but so far I am not able to. I'll keep trying though.
I'm running python 2.7.3

Okay so I think the problem is the 2 and the 1 are somehow "instance" typed instead of ints.
Thanks for the comment guys!

Comment: Am I correct to assume that `self.candidates` is a dictionary? If it is, you're comparing keys.

Comment: @l19: that would seem unlikely, since prev_cand appears to be a dictionary.

Comment: The output indicates the objects are **not** equal. What's the type of the key and value of both? String key, int value? Then what you describe can't happen. In any case, a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would be useful.

Comment: Running `{'H__0': 2} == {'H__0': 1}` gives the expected `False`. There is clearly some information missing from your question.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide the two objects themselves so that the problem could be reproduced? I'm guessing if you started the code with `prev_cand = {'H__0': 2}` and `cand = {'H__0': 1}` this problem wouldn't be able to be reproduced.

Comment: There is no bug here. The code indicates that these two dictionaries you are comparing are not equal (and they are not). What is the problem?

Comment: @dkar: The problem is the line `if prev_cand == cand:`, which seems to indicate they are.

Comment: @DavidRobinson oops sorry for a moment I thought it was inequality.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the problem to a small instance, so far I was not able to do so :(

Comment: @delnan printing the type for the key and value helped solving it. thanks.

Comment: You have an old-style class (`class Foo:` instead of `class Foo(object):`) somewhere with a confusing `__repr__`. Fix both, it's a recipe for annoying bugs.

Comment: the instances of your class that print 1 and 2 ( because of def __repr__(self)) are the same instances therefore it's equal.

Comment: @delnan I am using the Z3 python API which I have no control over haha

Comment: @evanthebouncy That class is from Z3? Ouch, I'd expect those guys to be a little more considerate. Then again, I just visited their web site and all entries in the TOC have turned into "undefined", so apparently they don't prove their software correct as one would expect (I'm not sure whether I'm joking...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instances of your class that print 1 and 2 ( because repr) are the same instance therefore it's equal. Basically you could have something like this :

```
class Test:
count = 0
def __init__(self):
    self.a = ["1","2"]
def __repr__(self):
    b = self.a[self.__class__.count]
    self.__class__.count += 1
    return b

>>> a = Test()
>>> b = a
>>> a == b
True
>>> print a, b
1 2
```